# how to called button click on java script moulder even in Kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have functionally where popup shown on add button click. I wanted to click that Add button on edit button.

please help me

My work around :

```
columns.Command(command => {
    command.Custom("Edit").Click("ItempopUpManager.btnAddClicked")
      .HtmlAttributes(new {
        @class = "btn btn-default"
      });
  }).Width(130)
  .Title(Resources.GetString(Constants.Edit));
```

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: @SangramNandkhile I got my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And Here I got my solution :

```
columns.Command(command => {
    command.Custom("Edit")
      .Click("ItempopUpManager.btnAddClicked")
      .HtmlAttributes(new {
        @class = "btn btn-default", @id = "btnId"
      });
  }).Width(130).HtmlAttributes(new {
    style = "height:30px;text-align:center"
  })
  .Title(Resources.GetString(GlobalConstants.Edit));
```